# get date for next time at 1am

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

In order to run a background service I want to scedule a thread for running daily at 1am. How can I get this date in java?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR_OF_EXECUTION);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go for [**Quartz**](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

- [Here is some sample code.](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/152-quartz-job-scheduler-example-code/)

OR

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
final Callable c = callable;
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
            c.call();
    }
}
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, firstExecuteDate, 86400000); // every day
```

Give firstExecuteDate accordingly and your thing has done, more over to get next execute - now

To get next date for time 1 pm.

```
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calAtOne  = Calendar.getInstance();
calAtOne.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);
calAtOne.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
calAtOne.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);

if(calAtOne.after(cal)){
    return calAtOne;
}else{
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
    return cal;
}
```

Then subtract `currentMillis - (nextExecDate returned By above code)`

Comment: I am using a timer. I thought i can get it work with 'timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);'. Is this not possible? I dont want to use another library if not necessary

Comment: @elCapitano It is possible , but the solution I gave is better, so you want when next it will executed ? if yes you can get an instance of calendar when you start timer and check if it is past 1 pm than add 1 day and set time to 1 pm, otherwise settime to 1 pm .

Comment: Currently i sart the timer with a period of 24h. My problem is that the first execution has to be at 1am (because all periods has to be executed at this time because of workload issues). I only need the java.util.Date of now + x hours = 1am.

Comment: @elCapitano you can configure it using quartz easily, then you just need to do next 1 pm  - now

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked. I can not use another library at the moment, but i will have a look at quartz. Thank you!